# Regular Expression for the search string

Tags: regex, bash

The command
    `grep -r CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID`gives me the following output:

```
printtimestamp.dir/DependInfo.cmake:SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID "GNU")
2.8.10.1/CMakeCCompiler.cmake:set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID "GNU")
2.8.10.1/CMakeCCompiler.cmake:set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID_RUN 1)
buildtimestart.dir/DependInfo.cmake:SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID "GNU")
buildtimeend.dir/DependInfo.cmake:SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID "GNU")
```

I want to extract the string `GNU` from this(Note that the string might not be GNU always, it may be some other compiler such as `CYGWIN`). What would be the regular expression I can use with `grep` to achieve this? Any other equivalent solution is also okay. This is to be used in a bash script.

Sorry if the question is too specific, I didn't know how to frame it otherwise.

Comment: do you want strings containing GNU ?

Comment: No, the output should be GNU(or any other compiler name set by CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID)

Comment: so you want the text written after CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `grep` supports [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), you could say:

```
grep -oPr 'CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID "\K[^"]*'
```

This would return the string within quotes after `CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID`.

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty close to what I want. How do I make grep not display the file name, and how do I ensure I get only 1(or the first) first?

Comment: @AnkeshAnand Pipe the result to `head` (to `head -1`, specifically) if you want only the first result.  If you don't want filename, say `grep -oPh 'CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID "\K[^"]*' * | head -1` instead.

Comment: That works, and it all makes sense. Thanks for the help. Could you also point me to a resource for more insight into this.

Comment: And is there some alternate solution for systems that don't support PCRE?

Comment: @AnkeshAnand Look at `grep` documentation: `info grep`.  Also look at the link provided in the answer.

Comment: @AnkeshAnand You might pipe the `grep` output to `awk` in that case:  `awk -F'"' '{print $(NF-1)}'`

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way:

```
awk '/CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID / && sub(/\)$/,"",$NF) && $0=$NF' inputFile
```

We tell awk:

- Look for lines matching our `regex` by stating pattern in `/../`
- If found, use `sub` function to discard the `)`
- If successful, print the last field

#### `gnu sed`:

```
sed -nr 's/.*CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID ([^)]+)\)$/\1/p' inputFile
```

With `sed`:

- We look for the line with your pattern
- Using captured group `(..)` grab everything upto `)`
- Print using back-reference `\1`
- `-n` disables default printing
- `p` enables printing on successful lines
- `r` allows us to make `sed` more readable. If `-r` is not supported you can use `-E`.

Comment: @AnkeshAnand Added a `sed` option. A return of favor for your up-vote! `:)`